# Rustlig if2 trying to convert 1 to "1" inside the function foo_if_fizz

Tags: rust, type-conversion, rust-rustlings

I'm new to rust and I'm looking for a way to convert 1 to "1" at compile time;

```
pub fn foo_if_fizz(fizzish: &str) -> &str {
    if fizzish == "fizz" {
        "foo"
    } else {
        &(1.to_string()). <-- returns a reference to data owned by the current function
    }
}
```

this error is completely logical, I'm aware of it. But how can we manage to do (Even if it requires the use of unsafe)?

I have an idea but I don't know if it is feasible.
I could allocate some memory space at compile time, like for example "0" which is an i32. Then inside the function, I could get the address then access the memory directly and change the value inside.

The questing is what is the best way

Comment: What is the problem with `"1"`?

Comment: For a literal, just put `"` around it... Otherwise you need to provide more details.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman "1" is the correct answer. 
But I was questioning myself of how can I convert it since rustling set 1 without having to do it like this "1"

Comment: I don't understand, where did you see it in rustlings?

Comment: @Jean-PaulAbi-Ghosn the original Rustlings code *does not* compile and part of that is because `1` is missing the quotes and thus not the same type as the "foo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you are looking for this one:

```
extern crate lazy_static;   
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

pub fn foo_if_fizz(fizzish: &str) -> &str {
    if fizzish == "fizz" {
        "foo"
    } else {
        lazy_static! {
            static ref ONE: String = 1.to_string();
        }
        &ONE
    }
}
```

*Nevertheless, the only correct answer to the question at hand is [Friedman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7884305/chayim-friedman)* `"1"`!